# SQL Server 2016 Job running forever

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I have created a SQL Server Job on SQL 2016. This is a job that runs a full backup from our backup utility DDBoost. When I execute the job, the backup completes in 5 mins for all databases. However, the job keeps running forever. Any ideas?

```
USE [master]
GO
DECLARE @returnCode int
EXEC   @returnCode = dbo.emc_run_backup 
' -c <FullyQualifiedName> -k -S 4 -l full -y +90d 
-a "NSR_DFA_SI=TRUE" -a "NSR_DFA_SI_USE_DD=TRUE" 
-a "NSR_DFA_SI_DD_HOST=adc-dd-02" -a "NSR_DFA_SI_DD_USER=ddboost" 
-a "NSR_DFA_SI_DEVICE_PATH=/sql-prod" 
-a "NSR_DFA_SI_DD_LOCKBOX_PATH=D:\Program Files\EMC DD Boost Modules\DDBMA\config"
-a "NSR_SKIP_NON_BACKUPABLE_STATE_DB=TRUE" 
-a "SKIP_BACKUP_PROMOTION=FALSE" "MSSQL$PRSQL01:"'

IF @returnCode <> 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Fail!', 16, 1)
END
```

Comment: What version of DDBoost? When you run this same code from a SSMS window, does it complete as expected, or does it seem to go on forever like the job? Does the DDBoost backup log give you any useful info? (Check D:\Program Files\EMC DD Boost Modules\DDBMA\logs\ddbmsqlsv.log) Is "FullyQualifiedName" literally in your code, or is that just for your post here? Is this scripted from the DDBoost GUI? Does the backup run and finish as expected when run from the GUI?

Comment: To give context to my posted answer, OP answered (in a now-deleted comment) that that the version of DDBoost was 3.0, and yes, it did the same thing when the script was run from SSMS.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a bug. Try scripting from the GUI directly and see if your syntax is wrong somewhere.

Since the problem still occurs when running the script by itself, it doesn't have anything to do with the fact that it is running from a job. My guess is that the EMC application isn't properly reporting back to the `dbo.emc_run_backup` stored procedure that is has finished.

If that's the case, I'll bet scripting to CLI (`ddbmsqlsv.exe`) instead of T-SQL might behave differently. (You would need to change the job step to CmdExec instead of T-SQL.)

This may be a version problem, from what I can tell DDBoost didn't officially add support for SQL 2016 until version 3.5:

> ## Changes in the Microsoft application agent 3.5
>
> The following list provides the changes in the Microsoft application agent 3.5:
>
> - Added support for SQL Server 2016

Can't find a public link, but this is from the *EMC® Data Domain® Boost for Enterprise Applications and EMC ProtectPoint™ Microsoft Application Agent* **Release Notes** for Release 3.5.x.x (EMC document #81497).

Even if it worked before, a recent update of SQL 2016 may have broken it.

So my recommendation would be to upgrade to 3.5.0.1 or 4.0.

If you are unable to do that, all I can recommend is opening a support case with EMC.